# PL/SQL convert rows to grouped columns

Tags: plsql

I'm not sure how to phrase this question, but I am trying to convert a row value into columns in PL/SQL.  I'm not a newbie, but I just can't figure how to go about doing this.  I have the following table data:

Name     Responsibility

---

Joe         Sales
Steve     Sales
Paul       Exec
Pete       Manager
John       Exec
Roger     Sec
Scott       Exec

I need to create a query that will return and display the data as follows:

Sales      Manager      Exec      Sec

---

Joe         Pete            John       Roger
Steve     Null             Scott       Null
Null        Null             Paul        Null

The problem I am facing is that the row data is not related to eachother in anyway. Can this even be done?

I appreciate any help anyone can offer on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be better if you give us your database version in the future.For exemple if you have Oracle 11g even if it isn't exectly what you want you can do something similar with [PIVOT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)

```
with pivot_data as (select rownum as no,emp_name,job_name from (
select 'Joe' as emp_name,'Sales' as job_name from dual union all
select 'Steve','Sales'    from dual union all
select 'Paul','Exec'     from dual union all
select 'Pete','Manager'  from dual union all
select 'John','Exec'     from dual union all
select 'Roger','Sec'      from dual union all
select 'Scott','Exec'     from dual))
select "'Sales'" as Sales,"'Exec'" as Exec,"'Sec'" as Sec,"'Manager'" as Manager
from pivot_data
pivot(max(emp_name) for job_name in ('Sales','Exec','Sec','Manager'))

SALES    EXEC    SEC    MANAGER
-------------------------------
                Roger    
        Scott        
        John        
Joe            
Steve            
        Paul        
                        Pete
```

Or if this isn't enough for you this PL/SQL does what you want.I tested it on 11g and i'm fairly certain that it would work with 10g et 9i but i can't guarantee anything for DB2 or PostGre :

```
declare
    cursor C1 is 
    select 'Joe' as emp_name,'Sales' as job_name from dual union all
    select 'Steve','Sales'    from dual union all
    select 'Paul','Exec'     from dual union all
    select 'Pete','Manager'  from dual union all
    select 'John','Exec'     from dual union all
    select 'Roger','Sec'      from dual union all
    select 'Scott','Exec'     from dual;
    varray_sales dbms_sql.varchar2_table;
    varray_exec dbms_sql.varchar2_table;
    varray_manager dbms_sql.varchar2_table;
    varray_sec dbms_sql.varchar2_table;
    i_sales number := 0;
    i_exec number := 0;
    i_manager number := 0;
    i_sec number := 0;
    n_line_aextr number;
    colwidth number := 30;
    line varchar2(120);
    function max_de_deux (i number,x number) return number is
    begin
        return case when i > x then i else x end;
    end;
begin
    dbms_output.enable(120);
    for l1 in c1 loop
        if L1.job_name = 'Sales' then
            i_sales := i_sales+1;
            varray_sales(i_sales) := L1.emp_name; 
        elsif L1.job_name = 'Exec' then
            i_exec := i_exec+1;
            varray_exec(i_exec) := L1.emp_name;
        elsif L1.job_name = 'Manager' then
            i_Manager := i_Manager+1;
            varray_manager(i_Manager) := L1.emp_name;
        elsif L1.job_name = 'Sec' then
            i_sec := i_sec+1;
            varray_sec(i_sec) := L1.emp_name;
        end if;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(rpad('Sales',colwidth,' ')||rpad('Exec',colwidth,' ')||rpad('Manager',colwidth,' ')
                              ||rpad('Sec',colwidth,' '));
    dbms_output.put_line(rpad('-',colwidth,'-')||rpad('-',colwidth,'-')||rpad('-',colwidth,'-')
                              ||rpad('-',colwidth,'-'));
    n_line_aextr := max_de_deux(i_manager,max_de_deux(i_sec,max_de_deux(i_sales,i_exec)));

    for l in 1..n_line_aextr loop
        line := '';
        if l <= i_sales then
            line := line || rpad(varray_sales(l),colwidth,' ');
        else 
            line := line || rpad(' ',colwidth,' ');
        end if;
        if l <= i_exec then
            line := line || rpad(varray_exec(l),colwidth,' ');
        else 
            line := line || rpad(' ',colwidth,' ');
        end if;
        if l <= i_manager then
            line := line || rpad(varray_manager(l),colwidth,' ');
        else 
            line := line || rpad(' ',colwidth,' ');
        end if;
        if l <= i_sec then
            line := line || rpad(varray_sec(l),colwidth,' ');
        else 
            line := line || rpad(' ',colwidth,' ');
        end if;
        dbms_output.put_line(line);
    end loop;                                  

end;



Sales          Exec           Manager        Sec            
------------------------------------------------------------
Joe            Paul           Pete           Roger          
Steve          John                                         
               Scott
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help and can see you spent time and thought in putting your answer together.  Your 1st answer is good and I learned from it.  As you noted, it does not quite give the results I was looking for due to the jagged display and inner dispersed null values.  Your second answer is also helpfull, but it seems I have to know my data values in advance as they are part of the query.  In my case the values change from day to day, so I'm not sure that is a viable solution.  I really appreciate the time you put in and learned some cool techniques nonetheless.  Thank you.